# How to compute $\iint\frac {\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}{\sqrt {x^{2}-3y^{2}}}$, $\ x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4x-3$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

**Question**

> $$\iint \dfrac {\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}{\sqrt {x^{2}-3y^{2}}},\quad x^{2}+y^{2}\leq 4x-3$$
>
> *Hint: use polar coordinates.*

**My Answer**

$\left( x-2\right) ^{2}+y^{2}\leq 1$ then $C(2,0) , r=1$

$$\iint \dfrac {r\,\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta }{r\sqrt {\cos ^{2}\theta -3\sin ^{2}\theta }}\Longrightarrow\int\dfrac {-\mathrm d\theta }{\sqrt {\left(1/2\right) ^{2}-\left( \cos \theta \right) ^{2}}}=-\sin^{-1} \left( 2\cos \theta \right)$$

boundary $0$ and $1$ for $r$ ? boundary $0$ and $2\pi$ for $\theta$?

Is my answer along with boundaries correct?

Comment: Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Yes the boundary are correct but we need to assume

- $x=2+r\cos \theta$

in order to have a correct parametrization for the circle.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try with
\begin{cases}
x=2+r\cos\theta,\\
y=r\sin\theta.
\end{cases}
where $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$, and $0\leq r\leq1$.

Comment: i tried and i realize my fault .However its too complicated inside of root. any suggestion for me @user 108128

Comment: @FMath Your hint was using polar coordinates, but I think you should use another substitution.

Comment: i agree but my teacher said use polar coordinates.@user108128

Comment: Another polar coordinates substitution is $x=r\cos$, $y=r\sin$ then $$\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6}\int_{\cos t-\sqrt{4\cos^2t+3}}^{\cos t+\sqrt{4\cos^2t+3}}\cdots$$ I think this might be simple but not sure, try it if you want!

Comment: it looks very hard but i'll try@user 108128